# How to write a class constructor that takes a single argument as a path to a file, open the file and read it into a list print the output

Tags: python, class, constructor, path

write a constructor with a single argument that contains the path to a file then opens the file and read the file into a list in python and print the output.

```
print("Welcom to the Calculon 5000")
user = input("What is the path to the bill? ")
print("The path you entered is C:\\Users\\allwa\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2Final Project\\data.txt")


class Calculon5000:
    from pathlib import Path
    path = Path('data.txt')

    def __init__(self, mypath='data.txt'):
        """Initializing attributes to describe a class"""
        self.mypath = mypath
        try:
            with open('mypath/to/data.txt', 'r') as file_object:
                raw_data = []
                for mypath in raw_data:
                    raw_data.append(mypath.strip('\n'))
                    mypath = file_object.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Was unable to find {mypath}")
            print(mypath)

    def get_descriptive_name(self, mypath):
        self.mypath = mypath



the_bill = Calculon5000("$200.00")
print(f"{the_bill.get_descriptive_name}"
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: This is the contents of the text file: prices
grapes: 4.00
oranges: 7.50
bread: 3.05
coke: 7.77
beef: 3.75
quantities
grapes: 1
bread: 2
coke: 8
beef: 1

Comment: The error is unable to be find data.txt

Comment: Now I'm getting this: Was unable to find $200.00
$200.00
<bound method Calculon5000.get_descriptive_name of <__main__.Calculon5000 object at 0x000002321DE56EF0>>

Comment: the code defines an argument `mypath` and then overwrites this in the `for loop`.... specifically, it takes the values on `raw_data` which is **an empty list** in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors which have compounded through the code. So i have listed them as comments:

In summary, the code starts well and the `__init__` is constructed properly. But then the code fails to perform the read statement.

A typical read looks like this:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Then it gets worse as the code creates an empty list `raw_data = []` and tries to iterate though this empty list.

And even more confused, the for loop had used the `mypath` as the placeholder whereas it was supposed to be the variable which stored the file name.

So really there are a few (critical) errors.

Finally, the print statement was missing a closing bracket.

Nevertheless, you tried. So i hope the above is helpful.

```py
print("Welcom to the Calculon 5000")
user = input("What is the path to the bill? ")
print("The path you entered is C:\\Users\\allwa\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2Final Project\\data.txt")


class Calculon5000:
    from pathlib import Path
    path = Path('data.txt')

    def __init__(self, mypath='data.txt'):
        """Initializing attributes to describe a class"""
        self.mypath = mypath
        try:
            with open(mypath, 'r') as file_object:          # <---- put mypath in this line.
                raw_data = file_object.read()               # <---- reading the file into raw_data

                item_list = []                              # <---- new list
                for item in raw_data:                       # <---- reading items
                    item_list.append(item.strip('\n'))      # <---- appending the list
                    mypath = file_object.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Was unable to find {mypath}")
            print(mypath)

    def get_descriptive_name(self, mypath):
        self.mypath = mypath



the_bill = Calculon5000("$200.00")
print(f"{the_bill.get_descriptive_name}")                   # <---- close the brackets on the print
```